# I am getting the Apach2 "It works!" page on my wordpress front page, but mydomain.local/wp-admin works

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache2

So I set up a wordpress website on my ubuntu machine. I am getting a problem i've never had before.
When I go to my domain's homepage with either wp.ryan-41.local or my IP, it shows the default "it works" page, while i'm not suppose to get it any more.
However when I go to wp.ryan-41.local/wp-admin/ I am able to login normally.

https://gyazo.com/d4b3945396b4e11a7aa6aa0145c5b7fd
here's a screencap highlighting my issue.

Anyone who knows what's wrong here? I'm able to login and fully configure my wordpress, but when I go to the homepage of the site itself, I get this.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually decided to just toss it out and start over. This worked, eventually, but it was a bunch of work. I think I might've done something weird earlier in the process with my scripts, so it must've gone wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving everything back one directory, because that's just what comes to my mind when I see that.

Comment: It's currently all located in the /var/www/html/wordpress folder. Do you suggest moving it one step back to the /var/www/html/ folder instead?

Comment: Either that or the other option I suggested, whichever one suits you best.

Comment: This is the one I would recommend, and to change your root back to /var/www/html because as I said in the other one I can't test out that method, but this one I somewhat can, and did.